# Updated angular-output-target binding to v0.0.5 in StencilJS. Seeing events fired twice in my angular example app

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component, stenciljs

We are using Stencil JS to develop web components. We also use different framework (Angular, Vue) binding provided by Stencil to generate a framework-specific package. This question is related to `angular-output-target` binding.

So I just updated the `angular-output-target`  to `v0.0.5` and I am seeing that all the `events(EventEmitters)` from our stencil component are firing twice (For example, If there is an event on click, on the click it fires twice). Everything was working fine with angular-output-target `v0.0.2`. Does anyone facing a similar issue??

Versions:
`@stencil/core: 2.0.3`
`@angular/core: 10.0.0`

> The proxy file generated from `v0.0.5` of `angular-output-target`
> package is slightly different from what it used to be. Let me show the
> difference below.

Consider this `my-badge` component below. I am seeing an extra `outputs:[]` being added to `@Component` decorator below in `v0.0.5`  (check comment in code). For version `0.0.2` this was missing.

For `v0.0.2`, the proxy generated outputs, only as part of
`proxyOutputs(this, this.el, ['myBadgeChange'])`

When I comment out the `outputs:[]` line, I do not see events firing twice.

Could this be a problem with my code or it has to do with the latest `angular-output-target` version??

**UPDATE:**

I just found the `bug report`  and `PR` in Stencil repo related to this issue.

Bug: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-ds-output-targets/issues/81

PR: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-ds-output-targets/pull/82

I tested with the above solution and it seems to solve the issue.

```
import { Components } from '../../../core/dist/loader';
import { MyBadge as IMyBadge } from '../../../core/dist/types/components/my-badge/my-badge';
export declare interface MyBadge extends Components.MyBadge {}
@ProxyCmp({
  inputs: ['closable', 'color', 'content', 'disabled', 'flipmode', 'size'],
})
@Component({
  selector: 'my-badge',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  inputs: ['closable', 'color', 'content', 'disabled', 'flipmode', 'size'],

  // HERE: THIS IS NEW IN V0.0.5
  outputs: ['myBadgeChange'], 

})
export class MyBadge {
  /** Event emitted when close icon is clicked */
  MyBadgeChange!: IMyBadge['MyBadgeChange'];
  protected el: HTMLElement;
  constructor(c: ChangeDetectorRef, r: ElementRef, protected z: NgZone) {
    c.detach();
    this.el = r.nativeElement;

    // HERE: OUTPUT ONLY EXISTED HERE IN V0.0.2
    proxyOutputs(this, this.el, ['myBadgeChange']);

  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's already an issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-ds-output-targets/issues/81

Comment: yeah and there is PR too: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-ds-output-targets/pull/82

Not sure if I can use the solution from PR..seems to resolve this.